# Python: How do I keep track of whether an object is still in 'use'?

Tags: python

I have a text editing program that hands out cursors to other parts of the program that require it. The cursor consists of a two part list, `[start, end]`, which needs to be updated every time text is inserted/removed (the start/end index gets moved forward or backwards).

When the cursor is no longer used, I want to stop updating it, since there are many and they are time consuming to update. By not in use, I mean that the object that requested it no longer references it - it no longer cares about it. (For example: it has a list of cursors to all search results for the word 'bob', and a new search was made for the word 'fred', so now it replaces its result list with a new list of new cursors... the old list and its cursors are no longer used.)

I can require that any object using the cursor calls a `.finished()` method when it no longer needs it. But it would be easier if I could detect when it is no longer being referenced by anything outside of the editor. How do I check this in python (I know the garbage cleanup maintains a list, and deletes it when no longer referenced)?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "using" a cursor?

Comment: The object that requested it no longer references it - it no longer cares about it. (For example: it has a list of cursors to all search results for the word 'bob', and a new search was made for the word 'fred', so now it replaces its result list with a new list of new cursors... the old list and its cursors are no longer used.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a *weak reference* from the `weakref` module to hold your cursor reference.

When the referent of a weak reference no longer has any strong (normal) references to it, the weakref will resolve to `None`.

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class Cursor: pass
... 
>>> _ = None # suppress special _ variable
>>> a = Cursor()
>>> r = weakref.ref(a)
>>> print r()
<__main__.Cursor instance at 0x1004a2bd8>
>>> del a
>>> print r()
None
```

You can put all those weakrefs in a collection (or use `WeakKeyDictionary`, `WeakValueDictionary`, or `WeakSet`) to keep track of the various cursors you have to update.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @nneonneo said, you should periodically scan through your list of cursor weak references and cull out the `None`s otherwise you will end up with an ever growing list of `None`s

Comment: Note that the `weakref` module provides `WeakSet` which automatically discards deleted elements :)

Comment: @nneonneo, cool. Docs don't mention whether the objects need to be hashable or not...seems they don't

Comment: Elements probably do have to be hashable, since it's a `set`. AFAIK it doesn't have the iteration-size-changed problems that dictionaries do, but don't quote me on it.

Comment: @nneonneo, you can add your `Cursor` instances to a `WeakSet` with no problems. The implementation could just be using the `id()`

Comment: Class instances are actually always hashable unless you override `__eq__` but not `__hash__` (if memory serves)